# Installation of mongodb guide

Tags: mongodb, installation, driver

I'm new in the world of mongodb and JDBC. I'd like to install mongodb driver so I visited a page of installation guide http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/installation-guide/ . The question is what to do with all these tags said in the page?

Answer (score 0):

those tags are maven tags , so if you are using a java project with maven , you have to put those tags on your pom.xml 
there is a tag "dependencies"  , inside of that tag you have to paste this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

if you arent using maven , you should download java driver from [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.0/mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar)